# "Overloaded" value constructors

Tags: haskell

In ["Making Our Own Types and Typeclasses"](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses) they give the following piece of code :

```
data Point = Point Float Float deriving (Show)  
data Shape = Circle Point Float | Rectangle Point Point deriving (Show)

surface :: Shape -> Float  
surface (Circle _ r) = pi * r ^ 2  
surface (Rectangle (Point x1 y1) (Point x2 y2)) = (abs $ x2 - x1) * (abs $ y2 - y1)  

nudge :: Shape -> Float -> Float -> Shape
nudge (Circle (Point x y) r) a b = Circle (Point (x+a) (y+b)) r  
nudge (Rectangle (Point x1 y1) (Point x2 y2)) a b = Rectangle (Point (x1+a) (y1+b)) (Point (x2+a) (y2+b))

main = do
    print (surface (Circle (Point 0 0) 24))
    print (nudge (Circle (Point 34 34) 10) 5 10)
```

As it stands the pattern matching against constructors is getting quite cluttered at the point

```
nudge (Rectangle (Point x1 y1) (Point x2 y2)) a b = ....
```

Had we defined the Shape type as :

```
data Shape = Circle Point Float | Rectangle Float Float Float Float deriving (Show)
```

Then even though we lose a bit of clarity into the nature of the type, the patten matching looks less cluttered, as can be seen below :

```
data Point = Point Float Float deriving (Show)  
data Shape = Circle Point Float | Rectangle Float Float Float Float deriving (Show)

surface :: Shape -> Float  
surface (Circle _ r) = pi * r ^ 2  
surface (Rectangle x1 y1 x2 y2) = (abs $ x2 - x1) * (abs $ y2 - y1)  

nudge :: Shape -> Float -> Float -> Shape
nudge (Circle (Point x y) r) a b = Circle (Point (x+a) (y+b)) r  
nudge (Rectangle x1 y1 x2 y2) a b = Rectangle (x1+a) (y1+b) (x2+a) (y2+b)

main = do
    print (surface (Circle (Point 0 0) 24))
    print (nudge (Circle (Point 34 34) 10) 5 10)
```

My question is whether it is possible to have both

```
Rectangle Point Point
```

and

```
Rectangle Float Float Float Float
```

in the same piece of code (i.e. a sort of "overloading" of value constructors), so that we can do something like :

```
...
surface (Rectangle (Point x1 y1) (Point x2 y2)) = (abs $ x2 - x1) * (abs $ y2 - y1)  

...
nudge (Rectangle x1 y1 x2 y2) a b = Rectangle (x1+a) (y1+b) (x2+a) (y2+b)
```

where the "..." denotes the same as in the code above. Also are there any other tricks to make the notation a bit more compact at the "nudge (Rectangle...." point? Thanks

Comment: Sounds a lot like the [PatternSynonyms](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/PatternSynonyms) proposal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could possibly use type classes to make a function behave as both `Point -> Point -> Rectangle` and `Float -> Float -> Float -> Float -> Rectangle`, but I wouldn't advocate it. It will be to much trouble for the gain. I don't think there's anyway you could make such an overloaded name usable in pattern matching anyway.

The way I see it, if you're only ever going to be using `Point` values by deconstructing them and operating on the raw `Float` values, then you're not really getting that much out of it, so you could resolve your problem by getting rid of it entirely.

But you're missing a golden opportunity to implement a function to adjust a point directly!

For starters I would make an `Offset` type to hold your `a` and `b` values. Then you make a function `adjust :: Offset -> Point -> Point` to do the combining. And then your `nudge` doesn't even need to understand the internal structure of a `Point` to do its job!

For example (Disclaimer: I haven't actually compiled this)<sup>1</sup>:

```
data Point = Point Float Float deriving (Show)
data Offset = Offset Float Float deriving (Show)
data Shape = Circle Point Float | Rectangle Point Point deriving (Show)

adjust :: Point -> Offset -> Point
adjust (Point x y) (Offset ox oy) = Point (x + ox) (y + oy)

nudge :: Shape -> Offset -> Shape
nudge (Circle c r) o = Circle (adjust c o) r  
nudge (Rectangle p1 p2) o = Rectangle (adjust p1 o) (adjust p2 o)
```

And similarly there could be a whole family of operations on `Point` and `Offset`. For example `offsetFrom :: Point -> Point -> Offset` could be useful in your `surface` function. I once went overboard and used type classes to implement a family of operators (`|+|`, `|*|`, etc IIRC) which allowed various things to be combined (for example, you can add a `Point` and an `Offset` in either order to get a `Point`, you can add and subtract `Offset`s but not `Point`s, you can multiply `Offset`s by scalars but not `Point`s, etc). Not sure whether it was worth it in the end, but it made my code look like my maths a little more!

With your current code you're effectively implementing all operations on `Point` again every time you need them (including the same adjustment operation twice in the same equation in `nudge`, which is my take on why it looks quite so bad).

---

<sup>1</sup> There's a certain argument to be made for making functions like `adjust` and `nudge` have signatures where the "main" thing being operated on comes last, so `adjust :: Offset -> Point -> Point` and `nudge :: Offset -> Shape -> Shape`. This can come in handy because then partially applying `adjust` gives you a "point transformer" with type `Point -> Point`, and similarly you can partially apply `nudge` to get a "shape transformer" with type `Shape -> Shape`.

This helps when you have a collection of points or shapes and you want to apply the same transformation to all of them, for example:

```
data Shape = Polygon [Point]

adjust :: Offset -> Point -> Point
adjust (Offset ox oy) (Point x y) = Point (x + ox) (y + oy)

nudge :: Offset -> Shape -> Shape
nudge o (Polygon ps) = Polygon (map (adjust o) ps)
```

And generally "transformers" with type `Something -> Something` are just useful things to have on your main data structures. So whenever you have a function that combines some auxiliary data with a `Something` to produce a new `Something`, it'll often turn out to be useful to put the `Something` as the last argument, so you have another easy source of transformer functions.

Comment: Hi I am not sure I understand the paragraph starting with "For starters I would make an Offset type to hold your a and b values....". Could you illustrate with a code example please, showing how you would cater differently for Circle and Rectangle? Thanks a lot.

Comment: and also I should add that my original aim was to seek a compactification of [`nudge (Rectangle (Point x1 y1) (Point x2 y2)) a b`]. Thanks

Comment: @artella I added example code. Hopefully this makes more sense now! The aim of my suggestions was to compactify `nudge` as well, by avoiding the need to think about coordinates at all and just call operations on `Point`s. You can do that and still keep an identical signature to what you had, but if you're abstracting away from the internal details of `Point` in `nudge`, then I think it's a little nicer not to take two `Float`s and instead take an abstract `Offset`. As a plus, that will make it **much** easier to later decide you want your points to use `Double` rather than `Float`.

Comment: that was an awesome & very insightful answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

One option would be to use [view patterns](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ViewPatterns). Let me give you a short example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

data Point = Point Float Float
data Shape = Circle Point Float | Rectangle Point Point

rectangleAsPoints :: Shape -> Maybe (Point,Point)
rectangleAsPoints (Rectangle a b) = Just (a,b)
rectangleAsPoints _               = Nothing

rectangleFromPoints :: Point -> Point -> Shape
rectangleFromPoints = Rectangle

rectangleAsCoords :: Shape -> Maybe (Float,Float,Float,Float)
rectangleAsCoords (Rectangle (Point x y) (Point a b)) = Just (x,y,a,b)
rectangleAsCoords _                                   = Nothing

rectangleFromCoords :: Float -> Float -> Float -> Float -> Shape
rectangleFromCoords a b c d = Rectangle (Point a b) (Point c d)

surface (rectangleAsPoints -> Just (Point x1 y1, Point x2 y2)) =
  (abs $ x2 - x1) * (abs $ y2 - y1)
surface (Circle _ r) = pi * r ^ 2

nudge (rectangleAsCoords -> Just (x1,y1,x2,y2)) a b =
  rectangleFromCoords (x1+a) (y1+b) (x2+a) (y2+b)
nudge (Circle (Point x y) r) a b = Circle (Point (x+a) (y+b)) r
```

For consistency's sake I implemented both views of rectangles as functions. This way the actual implementation of the Rectangle type can remain hidden.

Note how you can mix normal pattern matching and view patterns.

Comment: I do not want to define Rectangle as a type in its own right. What I want is for Rectangle to be a value constructor for type Shape as in `data Shape = Circle Point Float | Rectangle Point Point deriving (Show)`. Would it be possible for you please to modify your code to cater for the instance where we have defined both `data Point = ...` and `data Shape = ...`. Right now your code gives an error `Multiple declarations of 'Rectangle'` if shape is already defined. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is't possibile.  For the purposes of pattern matching you could use `ViewPatterns` as a poor-mans replacement for multiple constructors and make a single function to ease construction:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

-- Your pattern match aid
unRectangle :: Shape -> Maybe (Float, Float, Float, Float)
unRectangle (Rectangle (Point x1 y1) (Point x2 y2)) = Just (x1,y1,x2,y2)
unRectangle _ = Nothing

-- your construction aid
rectangle :: Float -> Float -> Float -> Float -> Shape
rectangle x y u v = Rectangle (Point x y) (Point u v)

surface (unRectangle -> Just (x1,y1,x2,y2)) = (abs $ x2 - x1) * (abs $ y2 - y1)
...
nudge (unRectangle -> Just (x1,y1,x2,y2)) = rectangle (x1+a) (y1+b) (x2+a) (y2+b)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks I managed to get that running fine. When I removed all instances of `Just`, `Maybe`, and removed the line `unRectangle _ = Nothing` the program still ran fine. What purpose do these keywords serve in the program?

Comment: They aren't keywords, it is a data type.  The `Maybe` data type allows you to return `Nothing`, a null constructor, or `Just a`.  In my code I used Maybe so you wouldn't have to get an exception when passing "surface" something besides a rectangle.  Without `Maybe` you won't be able to write `nudge` to handle a `Circle` and a `Rectangle` at the same time.  Using `unRectangle` on a parameter that is a circle  would cause an exception.